# Schengen Area Visa 90/180 days

Tags: schengen, canada, 90-180-visa-rules

I have a question about the Schengen Area View for Canadians. 
On August 30th 2017 I entered the Schengen Area ao on this date my 180 days started. From August 30th to September 12th I was in France. Went back to Canada. On January 26th, I entered again the Schengen Area (Spain). And now here I am. Still in Spain and my 180 days finish today (February 25th). 
My question is: Do I have to get out of the Schengen Area to start again my 90 days or it is automatically starting again my 90-180 days so technically I would have now right now here today 90 more days to stay in Spain?
Complicated, but very stressed and looking for an answer... Thank you!!!

Comment: There is no 'fixed' 180 days, not a restart of 180 days. It is a rolling period. Any day you can not have been in more than 90 days in the last 180 days. See more information in the Duplicate question. Especialy the days calculator.

Answer (score 3):

You're misunderstanding how the 90/180 day rule works. There's no concept of "my 180 days finish today" -- instead, **every day** a new 180-day period starts and in *each of those periods* you can only be in the Schengen area for 90 days.

In other words, **each day** you're supposed to look at how many of the *last 180 days* you've been inside Schengen. If that is less than 90, you're good.

Since you've been outside Schengen between September 13 and January 25, which is more than 90 days, everything that comes *before* this period outside cannot affect you now, and you're good to stay within the area until the 90th day of your stay that started in January.